# Questions about the facebook SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am looking at using the facebook SDK and I am wondering first what version should I be using?

It looks like some major changes are happened from 4.2 to 5(currently still in beta). Should I go ahead and use the beta? Anyone have any ides when it will be out of beta?

My second question is how can I use it for authentication.

Right now I am using DotNetOpenAuth to do all my openId authentication for my site. I am using there sort of plugin for facebook authentication(oAuth) however I am planning to use more facebook features on my site so I think it is kinda pointless to use this plugin and then the sdk libary when the library seems to be able to do it all.

Anways how do I do authentication with the sdk library. I want to have a button on my login page that they click it goes off to facebook they become authenticated and I get some request back saying that they where authenticated and then I give them a cookie and let them in.

All the tutorials I seen to have it that your just using facebook as your only authentication method but of course for me I have openId, facebook and twitter.

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website&referringTitle=Getting%20Started

Comment: Way too broad.  Would probably be better without asking whether to use the beta and the eta for 5's release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding 4.2 vs 5.0 BETA I guess you need to decide whether you want to use a BETA version or a stable version. I am sure they have a changelog in their BETA Release you can look at for the changes since the older version.

Regarding authentication using Facebook. I have a project where I support standard Forms authentication and accounts creation as well as Facebook login. In my AccountController I have  one action for Forms login and one for Facebook login.

To configure the Facebook assembly you can follow the tutorial you have posted, then you can put a Facebook button on your page and similar code to begin the authentication process:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '<%= FacebookSettings.Current.AppId %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

        $('#fbLoginButton').click(function () {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.session) {
                    // Success - execute our facebook login action.
                    window.location = "<%= Url.Action("FacebookLogin", "Account") %>";
                } else {
                    // user cancelled login or failed
                }
            }, { perms: 'email' });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

The facebook aciton works by:

1. Was Facebook Authentication successful?
2. Do we have a user with the Facebook Id as a username in the system?
3. If not create a user, populate name, email, etc from the Facebook data
4. Set the Forms authentication cookie

Pseudo code:

```
FacebookApp facebook = new FacebookApp ();
if (facebook.IsAuthenticated) {
        string userName = facebook.UserId.ToString();

        if (UsersRepository.ByUserName(userName ) == null) {
            // Create a User using the Facebook name, email, etc data
        }            
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie (userName , true);
}
```

So the idea is that I delegate the authentication to those 3rd party services and then create a user on my system with the information I can fetch from them. Also in my project, because I want the user to set/very some preferences after the account is created I redirect them to the page where they can do that.

P.S: A tip regarding running your web project locally in Visual Studio. You can create a private Facebook App with "Site URL" set to e.g. "http://localhost:4911/" and use that appId. This will allow you to play with Facebook locally.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Facebook SDK, and my advice for you would be to use the beta

The reason is because Facebook is changing and depreciating a lot of the Old REST interface and making Graph API the only way to access data.  So, to be future proof, the latest and greatest is the way to go.

Now, it is a beta, so everything isn't 100%.  If you **need** stability and don't mind making changes, then use the stable version and then upgrade later.

As for authentication, [the process to authenticate is pretty simple](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

you need your authURL:

```
string authURL = @"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + Settings.appId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl + permissions
```

where `appId` is your Facebook Application ID (you get it when you register your app with Facebook), the `redirectUrl` is the URL that you want Facebook to send you the challenge token, and your [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) are the list of things you want to access with your Facebook authentication Token

You make a popup or whatever that browses to that URL.  The user will login to facebook (if they haven't already) and then they will be presented with the app authorization screen (if they haven't already authorized the app).  Once they authorize (or imidiately if they already authorized), the page will be forwarded to the `redirectUrl` that you provided.  In the URL, there will be a GET variable called `code` that will contain the challenge string. You take that challenge code and add it as a query variable to another URL that is in the form of:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOURID&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_secret=YOURSECRET&code=THATCODE
```

That URL will return the authentication key...

Phew!  That's quite the process....  If done manually :)  Now that you know a little more about what's going on, you can appreciate what the SDK does for you.

To authenticate with the SDK, [Just follow the 19 simple steps as outlined in this link](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website&referringTitle=Getting%20Started)

Easy huh?